# Storage Reference Value Event Listener

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p5W4e.png)I am working on a project and getting help from some sources, but I am using firestore database. The source I use uses realtime database. How can I show this piece of code with storage reference?

I tried a few ways but I couldn't get the result I wanted.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, please [don't show pictures of text and code](https://overflow.tips/write-good-question/formatting-text-code#dont-use-screenshots-of-text). Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

Comment: If you're using Firestore, start from **its** documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quickstart

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Doug asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: Besides that, what do you mean by "storage reference"? Are you trying to read a file from Cloud Storage for Firebase?